# How to make stored procedure into a drop down list C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I thought I could do this easily however I'm running into an error, I'm trying to make a drop down list in MVC 5 which shows data that I have receive from a SQL stored procedure. I'm getting the correct number of drop down items (7) however all of the items are same repeated last value from the SQL data. I verify that my SQL stored procedure returns 7 different rows with different values that I want.

In my model:

```
public class FindHost
{
    public List<Details> Inform {get; set;}

    public FindHost()
    {
        Inform = new List<Details>();
    }
}

public class Details
{
    public string HostNames {get; set;}
    public string HostID {get; set;}
}
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult create(int? id)
{
    FindHost data = new FindHost();
    Details hosts = new Details();

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stored Procedure Name",connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", 343);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", 343);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                hosts.HostID = reader["hostID"].Tostring();
                hosts.HostNames = reader["hostName"].Tostring();
                data.Inform.Add(hosts);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    ViewBag.HostStuff = new SelectList(data.Inform,"HostID", "HostNames");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Create a new instance of `Details` within the loop (rather than outside of it) and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Kritner say:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    Details hosts = new Details();

    hosts.HostID = reader["hostID"].Tostring();
    hosts.HostNames = reader["hostName"].Tostring();
    data.Inform.Add(hosts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kritner and Juan, it works perfectly now!! Thanks again!